# Laravel nova File Field | How can i get resource id before storing file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-nova

I want to store a file with **resource id** + **extension** i.e 1.csv,2.csv,3.txt,4.jpeg.

I am using laravel nova **File Field** to upload file in s3 is there any way I can get the id of that row before storing in db?

below is the code I am using to uploading files.

```
File::make('path')
    ->disk(config('filesystems.default'))
    ->rules('required','mimes:csv,txt')
    ->storeAs(function (Request $request) {
        return $request->path->getClientExtension();
    })
   ->path('csv'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the last inserted record using the model then just increment the id `$nextId = YourModel::orderByDesc('id')->first()->id + 1`.

Comment: There should be some other way to get it ?

Comment: Only if the insertion is happening right before this within the same request lifecycle (then you can get it from the pdo instance)